# Adding meta data to Word Documents and Paragraphs using VSTO

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop

I have a **Word 2013 Document Add-in** and I want to save meta data at a document level which is used when the document is being edited. Similarly, I have meta data I also need to attach to specific paragraphs in the document so I can reflect over them and then enact various behaviors while the user is editing the document.  I am new to VSTO and not sure how non-visible meta data is stored and how they are linked to paragraph content. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this question?